# Automatic Seeding Fails in Always On Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, availability

I am running SQL Server Standard Edition 2016 (13.0.4001.0).

I create a new database and then create an Always On Availability Group using the wizard. I set `Synchronous Commit` for both replicas and use Active Directory account for authentication.

Always On Availability Group is created successfully, I can see in SQL Server Management Studio connected to other database. But replica database is not able to "fully" join Availability group.

Status of Availability Group on secondary is as:

[image: Secondary]

While its status on primary is as:

[image: Primary]

On manually join on secondary replica to Availability Group:

[image: Manual Add]

Corresponding entry in `sys.dm_hadr_automatic_seeding` is:

[image: Automatic Seeding Entry]

However if I manually share the database backup using remote shares, it works fine.

What could be the issue for this?

I have followed all steps in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alwaysonpro/2013/12/09/create-availability-group-fails-with-error-35250-failed-to-join-the-database/ and they checkout correct.